# Can't Connect To Wordpress on EC2 With Cloudfront and SSL

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, wordpress, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

- I have instantaudiobook.co registered at Name Cheap and pointing to AWS
  Route 53.
- I have CloudFront in front of my AWS server (just running
  WordPress).
- I created an SSL cert in AWS Certificate Manager and associated it with my domain via CloudFront.
- When I try to access my domain, I get various errors:

**Regular HTTP Request To My Domain:**

I get a Bad Request/403 error.

[image]

**Request To The Cloudfront Domain**

I get the same 403 error.

[image]

**HTTPS Request To My Domain**

Sometimes I get the same 403 errors. And sometimes I get an Unsupported Protocol error.

[image]

- Based on the SSL certs in Chrome and Safari, the certificate looks OK:

[image]
[image]

- Certificate Manager Setup:
  [image]

  - Route 53 DNS Setup:

[image]

- ec2 setup:

[image]

- CloudFront Setup:
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- Wordpress wp_config:

define('WP_HOME','https://instantaudiobook.co');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://instantaudiobook.co');

Comment: Why the -1? Please help me improve the question.

Comment: My first thought was it only says TLSv1, but a [test](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=instantaudiobook.co) says it supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2. Don't worry about a single downvote, your question looks fine to me. This can be fiddly to get working. I do remember having to define a subdomain "origin.example.com" and setting that as the origin so CloudFront wasn't trying to connect to itself

Comment: So you are using the same certficate on you AWS instance *and* the CloudFront Frontend? I didn't know this was possible. I'd use the AWS instance via HTTP and let CF do the HTTPS (and the redirect).

Comment: I did change the origin settings to use http and point the Public DNS, per the answer.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: "Please help me improve the question." -- well, for starters, there isn't *actually* question posed, as evidenced by the lack of a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your origin should be pointed to the host. In this example it looks like your origin is pointed to the cloudfront distribution as well. [See sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPtUf.png)

Comment: I change the origin to the origin to point to the Public DNS (IPv4)
(ec2-54-.....amazonaws.com). And now I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: @Brad, likely wordpress home in configuration table not matching actual host name, or make sure you clear caceh. Chrome Aggressively caches redirects

Comment: @BradRhoads use the answer from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193575/wordpress-cloudfront-flexible-ssl-ends-up-in-redirect-loop-https)

Comment: change the header though from X-FORWARDED-PROTO to CLOUDFRONT-FORWARDED-PROTO

Comment: @user1969510 Do you add this line to wp_conf.php:

if ($_SERVER['CLOUDFRONT-FORWARDED-PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

or do you mean something else?

I tried that. My current status is that I always get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: yes add that config